# setattribute doens't change the contentdocument?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the data of an object dynamically, but if I do the following, in the log, a will be the desired object with data source, but a.contentDocument is still the old document.

```
window.onload = function () {
  // Get the Object by ID
  var a = document.getElementById("tangramObj");
  a.setAttribute("data", files[file_count]);
  console.log(a, a.contentDocument);
  // Get the SVG document inside the Object tag
  var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
```

Object defined in index.html:

```
<object id="tangramObj" data="" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Is there anyway to guarantee that the data is set before accessing contentdocument?

Comment: How is setting `a.setAttribute("data"` supposed to change `contentDocument`? Aren't those completely separate attributes?

Comment: i think contentDocument is read-only, so the only way to change it is to change data of the object and access its contentdocument..

Comment: You need to wait for it to load after you changed the data attribute: `a.onload = function() { console.log(a.contentDocument); };`